# Sharing and observing data across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're using a tree-style navigation element which needs to allow other directives/controllers to know:

- What the current selection is, and
- When the row selection changes

I'm trying to determine the best angular-way to handle this.

Until now, we've been firing an event the entire app can listen to - less than ideal but ensures nothing is hard-coded to communicate directly with the component.

However, we now have a need to obtain the current selection when another component is activated. An event won't fly.

So I'm considering a service, some singleton which holds the current selection and can be updated directly by the tree, and read from by anyone who needs it.

However, this present some other issues:

- Would it be better to ditch the event entirely, and have components which need to know when it changes `$watch` the service's nodeId?
- If I use `$watch`, it seems like I should expose the object directly - so using getters/setters won't work unless I want to complicate the needed `$watch` code?

Part of my concern is that this would allow any component to *set* the value and this is intentionally not something we'll allow - the change will not impact the tree but will de-sync the service values from the true values, and will fire invalid `$watches`.

Comment: Does the entire application need to know the currentSelection, or a certain part of the website? Maybe store this information in the shared parent controller for all directives/controllers involved. Could you share some of the code involved (maybe in a plunker?)

Comment: It's a web app, so as you make a selection, a few other components need to know - this is part of why the event's worked well - plus it also goes one-way. Sharing a parent scope value might work too but the concerns I have remain - anything on the scope can set the value. I'd probably prefer a service just so we can make us of DI and avoid potential naming conflicts.

Comment: Could you explain what feels complicated about the intended $watch functionality - how are you planning to implement this?

Comment: I'm trying to determine how to implement this. A service or scope value means that whoever can `watch` it, can set the value. No one but the tree should be able to trigger a change of the selected node value but there's no way to deal with that in Angular. If I wrap the object property with getters/setters I now have to watch the getter rather than the data directly.

Comment: Can you use $routeParams to hold the selected node along with $locationChange events?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a getter should not lead to a complicated $watcher:

Service:

```
angular.service('myService', function() {
  var privateVar = 'private';
  return {
    getter: function() {
      return privateVar;
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.controller('myController', function(myService){
  $scope.watch(myService.getter, function(){
    //do stuff
  };
});
```

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kLDwFg9BtbkdfoSeE7qa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think using a service should work and you don't need any watchers for it.

In my demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ruvdvLqk/) I've added the following:

1. One service/factory `sharedData` that's storing the data - selection and items
2. Another service for eventing `sharedDataEvents` with observer/listener pattern.

To display the value in `component2` I've used one-way binding, so that component can't change the selection.

Also separating data from events prevents a component from changing the selection. So only `MainController` and `Component1` can change the selection.

If you're opening the browser console you can see the listeners in action. Only listener of `component3` is doing something (after 3 selection changes it will do an alert) the others are just logging the new selection to console.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', MainController)
 .directive('component1', Component1)
 .directive('component2', Component2)
    .directive('component3', Component3)
 .factory('sharedData', SharedData)
 .factory('sharedDataEvents', SharedDataEvents);

function MainController(sharedData) {
    sharedData.setItems([{
        id: 0,
        test: 'hello 0'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        test: 'hello 1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        test: 'hello 2'
    }]);
    this.items = sharedData.getItems();                  
 this.selection = this.items[0];
}

function Component1() {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
         selection: '='
        },
        template: 'Comp1 selection: {{comp1Ctrl.selection}}'+
        '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in comp1Ctrl.items" ng-click="comp1Ctrl.select(item)">{{item}}</li></ul>',
        controller: function($scope, sharedData, sharedDataEvents) {
            this.items = sharedData.getItems();
            this.select = function(item) {
                //console.log(item);
                this.selection = item
             sharedData.setSelection(item);
            };
            
            sharedDataEvents.addListener('onSelect', function(selected) {
             console.log('selection changed comp. 1 listener callback', selected);
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'comp1Ctrl'
    };
}

function Component2() {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
         selection: '@'
        },
        template: 'Comp2 selection: {{comp2Ctrl.selection}}',
        controller: function(sharedDataEvents) {
            sharedDataEvents.addListener('onSelect', function(selected) {
             console.log('selection changed comp. 2 listener callback', selected);
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'comp2Ctrl'
    };
}

function Component3() {
 //only listening and alert on every third change
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($window, sharedDataEvents) {
         var count = 0;
            sharedDataEvents.addListener('onSelect', function(selected, old) {
             console.log('selection changed comp. 3 listener callback', selected, old);
                if (++count === 3) {
                    count = 0;
                 $window.alert('changed selection 3 times!!! Detected by Component 3');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
function SharedData(sharedDataEvents) {
    return {
     selection: {},
        items: [],
        setItems: function(items) {
         this.items = items
        },
        setSelection: function(item) {
         this.selection = item;
            sharedDataEvents.onSelectionChange(item);
        },
        getItems: function() {
         return this.items;
        }
    };
}

function SharedDataEvents() {
 return {
        changeListeners: {
         onSelect: []
        },
        addListener: function(type, cb) {
         this.changeListeners[type].push({ cb: cb });
        },
        onSelectionChange: function(selection) {
            console.log(selection);
            var changeEvents = this.changeListeners['onSelect'];
            console.log(changeEvents);
            if ( ! changeEvents.length ) return;
            
         angular.forEach(changeEvents, function(cbObj) {
                console.log(typeof cbObj.cb);
                if (typeof cbObj.cb == 'function') {
                    // callback is a function
                    if ( selection !== cbObj.previous ) { // only trigger if changed
                        cbObj.cb.call(null, selection, cbObj.previous);
                        cbObj.previous = selection; // new to old for next run
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <p>Click on a list item to change selection:</p>
    <component1 selection="ctrl.selection"></component1> <!-- can change the selection -->
    <component2 selection="{{ctrl.selection}}"></component2> 
    <component3></component3>
</div>
```